# How to add a delay to the gupshup chat so that the chatbot opens after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, chatbot, gupshup

I've made a chatbot and deployed it locally on a wordpress website now i want to add a delay so that chatbot auto opens after 5 second the website is loaded, Using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I myself found the answer to this

```
<script id="gs-sdk" src='//www.buildquickbots.com/botwidget/v2/demo/static/js/sdk.js?v=2' key="5bxxxx1a-xxx2-xxxa-axx2-1xxxxxxxxa" onload="setTimeout(function(){tc.funcs.toggleWidget(true);}, 5000);"></script>
```