# How to delay the load of a chatbot?

Tags: javascript, chatbot

How can I delay the loading of a chatbot?
I want to load this bot after 10 seconds:

```
<script>var Chatbot={appId:"s45a589f2-72f4-4d76-9d2d-XXXXXXXXXX",mode:"livechat"};!function(t,a){var e=function(){(e.q=e.q||[]).push(arguments)};e.q=e.q||[],t.ChatbotApi=e;!function(){var t=a.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=1,t.src="https://widget.installchatbot.com/static/js/widget.js";var e=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}();}(window,document)</script>
```

I tried to address it by `getElementsByTagName("script")` but had no success.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955944/how-to-add-a-delay-to-the-gupshup-chat-so-that-the-chatbot-opens-after-5-seconds

Answer (score 1):

You could load the script dynamically with JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var bot = document.createElement('script');
    bot.innerHTML = "<script>var Chatbot={appId:"s45a589f2-72f4-4d76-9d2d-XXXXXXXXXX",mode:"livechat"};!function(t,a){var e=function(){(e.q=e.q||[]).push(arguments)};e.q=e.q||[],t.ChatbotApi=e;!function(){var t=a.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=1,t.src="https://widget.installchatbot.com/static/js/widget.js";var e=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}();}(window,document)</script>";
    document.head.appendChild(bot);
 }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<script> var Chatbot={appId:"s45a589f2-72f4-4d76-9d2d-XXXXXXXXX",mode:"livechat"};
 window.addEventListener('load', function() { setTimeout(function() { !function(t,a)
{var e=function(){(e.q=e.q||[]).push(arguments)};e.q=e.q||
[],t.ChatbotApi=e;!function(){var t=a.createElement("script");
t.type="text/javascript",t.async=1,t.src="https://widget.installchatbot.com/static/js/widget.js";
var e=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}();}(window,document); }, 10000) }) </script>
```